# Why does the determinant vanishing imply nontrivial solutions for a set of differential equations?

Tags: functional-analysis, functions

Why does this set of equations have to be singular?
If the determinant doesn't vanish, what does this imply?
I'm a mathmatically inclined materials science student, so I'll probably understand explanations on the level of a math student who has finished PDE's.

Answer (score 0):

The determinant of what? In general, you can probably get some good intuition by thinking about systems of linear quations. For a matrix $ A$, the equation
$$Ax=0$$
will only have a nontrivial solution if $A$ is not invertible or, equivalently, if $\det A = 0$.

In PDE (or more generally, in functional analysis), this principle is expressed in the Fredholm alternative.

If you can clarify what determinant you're asking about, I can edit this answer to better address your question.

Comment: The fredholm alternative got me started, thanks!

Comment: Awesome! Glad I could help.